# Converting a Cognos XML Schema file to XML using Javascript code

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, cognos

I found many "converters" online that will do this for you, but I haven't been able to find any source code that I can easily implement. I was wondering if anyone would be so kind to provide me with suggestions or even provide me with code that will do this task for me. I am trying to convert to XML so it will be easier to parse.

I am trying to convert this (Cognos XML Schema)...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <!-- 
<dataset
    xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd"
>


--> 
- <metadata>
  <item name="ROOT_NODE_ID" type="xs:decimal" precision="38" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL1_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL1_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL2_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL2_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL3_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL3_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL4_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL4_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL5_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL5_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL6_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL6_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL7_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL7_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL8_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL8_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL9_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL9_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL10_ID" type="xs:string" length="2002" /> 
  <item name="LEVEL10_NAME" type="xs:string" length="512" /> 
  </metadata>
- <data>
- <row>
  <value>5</value> 
  <value>5</value> 
  <value>Global Root</value> 
  <value>41</value> 
  <value>Company</value> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  </row>
- <row>
  <value>5</value> 
  <value>5</value> 
  <value>Global Root</value> 
  <value>41</value> 
  <value>Company</value> 
  <value>101590</value> 
  <value>Customer</value> 
  <value>101591</value> 
  <value>Customer -All Sites</value> 
  <value>125083</value> 
  <value>Site 1</value> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value xs:nil="true" /> 
  </row>
  </data>
  </dataset>
```

To this (XML)....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <ROOT_NODE_ID>5</ROOT_NODE_ID>
    <LEVEL1_ID>5</LEVEL1_ID>
    <LEVEL1_NAME>Global Root</LEVEL1_NAME>
    <LEVEL2_ID>41</LEVEL2_ID>
    <LEVEL2_NAME>Company</LEVEL2_NAME>
    <LEVEL3_ID></LEVEL3_ID>
    <LEVEL3_NAME></LEVEL3_NAME>
    <LEVEL4_ID></LEVEL4_ID>
    <LEVEL4_NAME></LEVEL4_NAME>
    <LEVEL5_ID></LEVEL5_ID>
    <LEVEL5_NAME></LEVEL5_NAME>
    <LEVEL6_ID></LEVEL6_ID>
    <LEVEL6_NAME></LEVEL6_NAME>
    <LEVEL7_ID></LEVEL7_ID>
    <LEVEL7_NAME></LEVEL7_NAME>
    <LEVEL8_ID></LEVEL8_ID>
    <LEVEL8_NAME></LEVEL8_NAME>
    <LEVEL9_ID></LEVEL9_ID>
    <LEVEL9_NAME></LEVEL9_NAME>
    <LEVEL10_ID></LEVEL10_ID>
    <LEVEL10_NAME></LEVEL10_NAME>
 </row>
 <row>
    <ROOT_NODE_ID>5</ROOT_NODE_ID>
    <LEVEL1_ID>5</LEVEL1_ID>
    <LEVEL1_NAME>Global Root</LEVEL1_NAME>
    <LEVEL2_ID>41</LEVEL2_ID>
    <LEVEL2_NAME>Company</LEVEL2_NAME>
    <LEVEL3_ID>101590</LEVEL3_ID>
    <LEVEL3_NAME>Customer</LEVEL3_NAME>
    <LEVEL4_ID>101591</LEVEL4_ID>
    <LEVEL4_NAME>Customer -All Sites</LEVEL4_NAME>
    <LEVEL5_ID>125083</LEVEL5_ID>
    <LEVEL5_NAME>Site 1</LEVEL5_NAME>
    <LEVEL6_ID></LEVEL6_ID>
    <LEVEL6_NAME></LEVEL6_NAME>
    <LEVEL7_ID></LEVEL7_ID>
    <LEVEL7_NAME></LEVEL7_NAME>
    <LEVEL8_ID></LEVEL8_ID>
    <LEVEL8_NAME></LEVEL8_NAME>
    <LEVEL9_ID></LEVEL9_ID>
    <LEVEL9_NAME></LEVEL9_NAME>
    <LEVEL10_ID></LEVEL10_ID>
    <LEVEL10_NAME></LEVEL10_NAME>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Why do you need Javascript to fix this for you and no the server side technology.  I think this question needs a little more detail regarding what you have tried, and why you are stuck.

Comment: Trying to solve this with JS will get you nowhere. If you want to transform from the default Cognos Xml report to your desired Xml structure you can do this by Xslt. I already did this but will need some time to find my sample code since I moved over to using a Webservice from the SDK. If you can use the Cognos SDK (i.e. if you took the extra cost and bought it) I could provide an example for that as well.

Comment: Thank you Filburt, I would love to see your sample code. And I do have the SDK but to my knowledge, that is only for Java and C#? I need to do this is javascript because I am recreating the Cognos tree object in javascript which I am then going to implement in a Cognos report inside an HTML object. My BI team has assigned me this because since our tree node list is so long, the Cognos tree object does not work for us anymore. But I am looking forward to your pieces of sample code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Xslt strip any schema metadata from arbitrary Cognos reports - **Xml output method** - and create result elements with names extracted from the metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:cog="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="//comment()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:dataset">
        <rows>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </rows>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:metadata">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:item">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@name | @type | @length | @precision" />

    <xsl:template match="cog:data">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:row">
        <row>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:value">
        <xsl:variable name="currentposition" select="count(./preceding-sibling::cog:value)+1" />
        <xsl:variable name="currentname" select="//cog:metadata/cog:item[$currentposition]/@name" />
        <xsl:element name="{$currentname}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If however you want to **make Cognos apply a server-side transformation**, you'll have to choose the **XHTML** output method which will make the transformation a little easier since each field will carry its actual name instead of *value*.

Comment: @Filbert, I know it's been a long time since you posted this but I found your post and last comment describing exactly what I need right now. When we export via Cognos Analytics 11.1 R6 to XML we see that all fields carry 'value' instead of the actual name. Do you know where I can find the option XHTML output method you mention since I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @Stackberg It's indeed a long time an I did not work with Cognos since 2012. Maybe [outputFormatEnum](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_dg_sdk.doc/r_d15e1278724.html) holds a clue where you could set the XHTML output format.