# parse xml in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I am given an XML file. It is formed like this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd">
-->
<metadata>
    <item name="Level" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
    <item name="ID" type="xs:string" length="14"/>
    <item name="Name" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
</metadata>

<data>
    <row>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>101   </value>
        <value>Location 1</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>103   </value>
        <value>Location 2</value>
    </row>
</data>
```

I am having trouble parsing this. There are hundreds of articles online - but all of them have a different format than the data handed to me.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for VB.NET on Framework 3.5?
I am used to seeing data more like this:

```
    <item name="Future" collected="yes">
```

EDIT:
So, I have tried this:

```
Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(fileToSave)

Do While (reader.Read())

Select Case reader.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name)
                        Console.WriteLine(">")
                    Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value)
                    Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name)
                        Console.WriteLine(">")
                End Select
            Loop
```

What I need is the Row items to be able to populate a combobox - this just gives me the same thing as the XML file:

```
    <dataset>
<metadata>
<item>
<item>
<item>
</metadata>
<data>
<row>
<value>
2
</value>
<value>
101   
</value>
<value>
Location 1
</value>
</row>
<row>
<value>
2
</value>
<value>
103   
</value>
<value>
Location 2
</value>
</row>
</data>
</dataset>
```

Comment: Have a look at [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Comment: What are you trying to query from the XML? Show us the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: That's just it Ahmad, I do not know where to start. I need the values from the <row> tags.

Comment: Try `DataSet.ReadXml`.

Comment: Tried that... each row value has the same name - so I get the items all in 1 column - not in 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract data from XML in VB.Net, you could simply use VB.Net's XML literals (if you don't want to bother with [XML transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129829/142637)).

Given your xml:

```
Dim xml As XDocument =  
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <metadata>
                        <item name="Level" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
                        <item name="ID" type="xs:string" length="14"/>
                        <item name="Name" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
                    </metadata>
                    <data>
                        <row>
                            <value>2</value>
                            <value>101   </value>
                            <value>Location 1</value>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <value>2</value>
                            <value>103   </value>
                            <value>Location 2</value>
                        </row>
                    </data>
                </dataset>
```

you can import its namespace with

```
Imports <xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
```

and then simply query your data like in the following examples:

```
For Each element In xml...<value>
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value)
Next

Console.WriteLine("----------")

For Each element In xml...<row>
    For Each v in element.<value>
        Console.WriteLine(v.Value)
    Next
Next

Console.WriteLine("----------")

For Each element In xml...<row>
    Dim s = element.<value>.Select(Function(e) e.Value.Trim())
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" - ", s))
Next
```

Output:

```
2
101   
Location 1
2
103   
Location 2
----------
2
101   
Location 1
2
103   
Location 2
----------
2 - 101 - Location 1
2 - 103 - Location 2
```

Comment: I had to do "for each element as xelement in xml...<value>" and it works great! thank you for this easy to use code.  By the way, what is "xml...<value>" -  I am pretty new to XML.

Comment: The last one does not work: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WLC.exe
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer below should be to your liking.  Most of my comments/editorials should explain the whole process.  Turns out you're not the only person on stackoverflow having cognos dataset woes, lol.  The example below was tested in LinqPad and returned desirable results.

```
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
Public Class Test

    'Note: If you don't put the <?xml...?> doctype the XML literals VB.NET gives you will not create an XDocument, but an XElement

    ' This the sample XML document from your question
    Private _xml As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!--
        <dataset
            xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd">
    -->
    <metadata>
        <item name="Level" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
        <item name="ID" type="xs:string" length="14"/>
        <item name="Name" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>101   </value>
            <value>Location 1</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>103   </value>
            <value>Location 2</value>
        </row>
    </data>
    </dataset>

    ' This is a transform I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465674/converting-a-cognos-xml-schema-file-to-xml-using-javascript-code, you're not the only one having trouble with this
    Private _xmlTransform As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:cog="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:template match="//comment()" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="cog:dataset">
            <rows>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </rows>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="cog:metadata">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="cog:item">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@name | @type | @length | @precision" />

        <xsl:template match="cog:data">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="cog:row">
            <row>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </row>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="cog:value">
            <xsl:variable name="currentposition" select="count(./preceding-sibling::cog:value)+1" />
            <xsl:variable name="currentname" select="//cog:metadata/cog:item[$currentposition]/@name" />
            <xsl:element name="{$currentname}">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>

    ' This is the XSLT .NET object that will allow us to translate your dataset into something usable
    private _tranform As XslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform()

    ' Meat & Potatoes, where the dataset will be set to
    public Property MainDataSet As DataSet

    Sub Main
        ' using XDocument, we can create a reader and then prepare the tranform...
        _tranform.Load(_xmlTransform.CreateReader(), new XsltSettings(true,true), Nothing)

        ' I am using "Using" here because, but you're more than welcome to use .Dispose, I'm a C# dev at heart, I'm just forced to code VB.NET for my day job
        Using _ds = new DataSet()   
            ' The XmlTextWrite constructor allows a StringBuilder; which will keep everything in-memory, per your comments
            Dim _sb As StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()

            ' Create an XmlTextWriter with the StringBuilder as the output-buffer
            Using _xmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(_sb)                    
                ' Commit tranformation of the original dataset xml
                _tranform.Transform(_xml.CreateReader(), _xmlWriter)

                ' Have the interim DataSet read-in the new xml 
                _ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(_sb.ToString()), XmlReadMode.Auto)

                ' ... keeping it clean here... lol
                _xmlWriter.Close()

                ' Set the class property to the rendered dataset. 
                MainDataSet = _ds
            End Using       
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Seems, stackoverflow still doesn't have a grip on xml literals in vb.net, if you would like better code coloring I have the code cloned [here](https://gist.github.com/Steinerd/bee0b45475ffcd09e032)

Comment: Another XSL transformaton that also works fine with `DataSet` can be found here: [IBM Cognos BI: generic XSLT normalization for table data](http://code.dblock.org/ibm-cognos-bi-generic-xslt-normalization-for-table-data)

Comment: Did my answer help?  This is all new to me, and I appreciate learning new things, just wondering if my execution of it was in scope. Lol

Comment: I think you answer is helpful (since finally extracting the values from a `DataSet` is trivial), so I voted it up. You should stop using lol, though :-)

Comment: @Steiner, see this link on [Color Coding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Problem is, it did not know which to use based on the fact there are 2 langage tags.

Comment: @Steve, that is wonderful; thanks for the extra information. I will bookmark it

Comment: This looks nice and stuff - I am having trouble understanding where I put this transform template.

Comment: You can either load it as a file relatively to the assemblies running the code, or you can have it as a app setting which can be gotten by as a stream, or use it in-memory like I used it above, the ladder of which isn't ideal. 

However, I was unaware you could import Schemas in VB.NET, @DominicKexel's answer is much better.

Comment: Steiner - I like it too - much easier... but having an issue with the string.join line.

Comment: @CRAIGRY I tried; But I don't actually have the IBM product nor the xsd to import; otherwise I'd try to see the issue for myself and if there is a solution for it.

Comment: Thatprocess doesn't require an XSD - just IMPORT the URL "<xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">" in VB project properties and then run the code after you open the XML Document or simply declare the XML and insert it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines` or `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` method, and set the extension as XML

Comment: Joe, if I was trying to write an XML file, I would. But  need to parse the file and get the <row> data.