# Converting Congnos 10 XML Data via XSLT to an easier to loop through XML File

Tags: xml, xslt, cognos, cognos-10

I found an almost fully functioning answer here titled: Converting a Cognos XML Schema file to XML using Javascript code

[Converting a Cognos XML Schema file to XML using Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465674/converting-a-cognos-xml-schema-file-to-xml-using-javascript-code)

The only problem I am having with Filburt's awesome solution is that
1. the root node  doesn't seem to be creating. (using Altova's XMLSpy)

I was using Altova's xmlspy when I was trying to learn how to create xslt conversions.

I also noticed that Congnos 10 is creating the XML metadata tags with Spaces (which xslt doesn't seem to like Throwing a QName error) on i.e. First Name. When trying to use Filburt's genius bit of code.

Once I removed all of the spaces in the items names in the metadata nodes I was able to get the file transforming correctly minus the top rows tag.

Any Idea why that wouldn't be working?

Also I was trying to build my own xlst file for this and the only output I would get was

Sample XML file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Congnos2BetterXMLversionSkills.xslt"?>
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
<dataset
xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd">
-->
<metadata>
    <item name="EmployeeName" type="xs:string" length="2414"/>
    <item name="LastName" type="xs:string" length="202"/>
    <item name="FirstName" type="xs:string" length="202"/>
    <item name="FormerLastName" type="xs:string" length="202"/>
    <item name="EmailAddress" type="xs:string" length="102"/>
    <item name="Skill" type="xs:string" length="2002"/>
</metadata>
<data>
    <row>
        <value>Public, John</value>
        <value>Public</value>
        <value>John</value>
        <value xs:nil="true"/>
        <value>jpublic@email.com</value>
        <value>Language - French</value>
    </row>

</data>
</dataset>
```

Xslt file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <data>
            <xsl:for-each select="/dataset/data/row">
                <row>
                    <Employee_Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="value[1]"/>
                    </Employee_Name>
                    <Last_Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="value[2]"/>
                    </Last_Name>
                    <First_Name></First_Name>
                    <Former_Last_Name></Former_Last_Name>
                    <Email_Address></Email_Address>
                    <Skill></Skill>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it perhaps the underscores in the tags?
I only implemented part of it as to make sure I was on the right track.

I get this as output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with namespaces. The Cognos XML starts like this:

```
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" ...
```

This means the `dataset` element, and all descendant nodes are part of a namespace. However, there is no reference to this namespace in your XSLT, and so it is looking for elements that are in no namespace. A `dataset` element in no namespace is a different element to one that is part of a namespace.

If you look at the answer you have linked to, you will see how the namespace prefix `cog` is defined on the stylesheet, and how all the nodes in xpath expressions use this prefix. You need to do the same.

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cog="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <data>
            <xsl:for-each select="/cog:dataset/cog:data/cog:row">
                <row>
                    <Employee_Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="cog:value[1]"/>
                    </Employee_Name>
                    <Last_Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="cog:value[2]"/>
                    </Last_Name>
                    <First_Name></First_Name>
                    <Former_Last_Name></Former_Last_Name>
                    <Email_Address></Email_Address>
                    <Skill></Skill>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Okay, Tim C That indeed does work does it have to be Cog: in all of those spots or can you do it like this?

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <library>
   <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" 
     namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     >library_schema.xsd</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:for-each select="//book">

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, you will have to prefix every xpath expression with `cog:`. In XSLT 2.0, there is a `xpath-default-namespace` option you can use.